# How to write factories which follow the Dependency Injection pattern?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory

I'm new to DI pattern, thus, here is my question.

### Edit 11 apr.

If I have certain factory that implements some business logic and at runtime creates its main object and its dependencies, depending on input arguments given, how should I implement it so that it wouldn't break the DI principle? (Should it avoid directly calling the new operator to instantiate its main object (being produced by this factory) and its dependencies, shouldn't it?)

(end of edit 11 apr)

Consider the following CarFactory exemple:

```
interface IEngine {}

class RegularEngine implements IEngine {}

class AdvancedEngine implements IEngine {}

class Car
{
    private $engine;

    public function __construct(IEngine $engine)
    {
        $this->engine = $engine;
    }
}

class CarFactory
{
    public function __invoke(bool $isForVipCustomer = false): Car
    {
        // @todo Here, CarFactory creates different Enginges and a Car,
        // but they should be injected instead?
        $engine = $isForVipCustomer ? new AdvancedEngine : new RegularEngine;
        return new Car($engine);
    }
}

// And here is my composition root:
$carFactory = new CarFactory;
$carForTypicalCustomer = $carFactory();
$carForVipCustomer = $carFactory(true);
```

Now, as you can see, my factory implementation breaks the DI principle: instead of receiving instances from the invoking code (from Injector, if I use DI container), it creates them by itself. So, I tried to rewrite it so that it doesn't break the DI principle. Here is what I got:

```
interface ICarSimpleFactoryForCarFactory
{
    public function __invoke(IEngine $engine): Car;
}

interface IEngineSimpleFactoryForCarFactory
{
    public function __invoke(): IEngine;
}

class CarFactory
{
    private $carSimpleFactory;
    private $regularEngineSimpleFactory;
    private $advancedEngineSimpleFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ICarSimpleFactoryForCarFactory $carSimpleFactory,
        IEngineSimpleFactoryForCarFactory $regularEngineSimpleFactory,
        IEngineSimpleFactoryForCarFactory $advancedEngineSimpleFactory
    )
    {
        $this->carSimpleFactory = $carSimpleFactory;
        $this->regularEngineSimpleFactory = $regularEngineSimpleFactory;
        $this->advancedEngineSimpleFactory = $advancedEngineSimpleFactory;
    }

    public function __invoke(bool $isForVipCustomer = false): Car
    {
        $engine = ($isForVipCustomer ? $this->advancedEngineSimpleFactory :
            $this->regularEngineSimpleFactory)();
        return ($this->carSimpleFactory)($engine);
    }
}

// And here is my composition root:
// (sinse I'm now using DI, I need to inject some dependencies here)
$carFactory = new CarFactory(
    new class implements ICarSimpleFactoryForCarFactory {
        public function __invoke(IEngine $engine): Car
        {
            return new Car($engine);
        }
    },
    new class implements IEngineSimpleFactoryForCarFactory {
        public function __invoke(): IEngine
        {
            return new RegularEngine;
        }
    },
    new class implements IEngineSimpleFactoryForCarFactory {
        public function __invoke(): IEngine
        {
            return new AdvancedEngine;
        }
    }
);
$carForTypicalCustomer = $carFactory();
$carForVipCustomer = $carFactory(true);
```

I had to introduce 2 new interfaces of small factories whose only responsibility is to give the opportunity to the Dependency Injector to inject instances to them and, respectively, to main CarFactory. (If I use DI container.)

It seems to me, that such a solution is overcomplicated and breaks the KISS design principle: just to move the use of “new” operator from my classes to composition root, I had to create an interface and its implementation, only to let the injector do its work?

So, what is the correct way to implement factories, following DI pattern?
Or, the solution provided by me is the only correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 5):

I think the entire discussion depends on where in your application do you need your cars, how often, and in what kind of variety.

First things first: Your initial factory is already horrible. Using __invoke() does not really help making the code calling this method clear, and using a boolean parameter to switch between the only two implementations likely is a violation of other good principles, because you restrict the result of this factory to two possible outcomes.

But apart from that, the essential question is: How many cars does your application need, and when. Take the example of doing exactly the same with database connection classes: You'd probably only need exactly one type of database at any given time for one task, so the class encapsulating the code to query the database will require an instance of the database interface in its constructor just like your IEngine interface.

Because the object allowing high level database access is considered a long term object (it will be eventually created once, then live for as long as needed, and only be destroyed when the PHP script ends), it's creation should take place at the composition root. How?

A factory class that needs to be instantiated is not necessary! It's overkill. Back to your car example, at the end of your script you need an instance of `car` with an engine inside, and it should be the only car needed her for a moment.

Instead of writing:

```
$carFactory = new CarFactory;
$carForTypicalCustomer = $carFactory();
$carForVipCustomer = $carFactory(true);
```

you can also write

```
$engine = new RegularEngine;
$carForTypicalCustomer = new Car($engine);
```

No factory at all.

Imagine instead of programming cars yourself, you use a library. It would be tedious to always remember how to create cars from this vendor (perhaps you always forget where you put the manual for this), so it is more convenient to put the code creating a car into a function - or even into a static method of a factory class:

```
class CarFactory {
    static public getInstance() {
        $engine = new RegularEngine;
        return new Car($engine);
    }
}
# and in your code
$carForTypicalCustomer = CarFactory::getInstance();
```

This separates the knowledge of doing all the tiny details from the actual place where just the whole thing is needed.

I skip the discussion about customizing the output of above factory because it would be easy to either add in the boolean parameter, or allow a string with a class name, or allow an instance of the IEngine interface or anything, because that's irrelevant to my point.

Let's think about a different situation: Instead of your application needing one car object for the whole application life, it has a certain place where new car objects have to be produced in huge amounts (just think of trying to send emails to different recipients or something like this). Such a car object does not belong into the composition root. The other class in need of unlimited amounts of car objects needs a factory instance to create new cars. And this other object belongs to the composition root, and there it must get the CarFactory injected. How to do this: Scroll back to the start of this answer, it is a recursive process.

Your overwhelming amount of additional interfaces for your second car factory comes from the fact that you started to create a dependency injection framework. Maybe you should continue for educational purposes, but I would consider this useless. There are very nice and small examples of DI frameworks available, one of them even fits into a tweet with less than 140 characters. Lets look at it: http://twittee.org/

```
class Container {
 protected $s=array();
 function __set($k, $c) { $this->s[$k]=$c; }
 function __get($k) { return $this->s[$k]($this); }
}
```

That's all you need for a fully working DI container. What does happen in there? You create an instance and then add "properties" to it, which will trigger calling the magic `__set` method and internally save the parameter to an array.

You have to assign closures (and note that there is no error checking, so dont use it in production). This is simple for scalar values like DB connection parameters, or the color of a car. In order to do something useful, you can also assign closures that accept one parameter, the DI container itself, and should return whatever you desire.

Let's configure your first car example:

```
$c = new Container();
$c->car = function ($c) {
    return new Car($c->engine);
}
$c->engine = function () {
    return new RegularEngine();
}
$carForTypicalCustomer = $c->car
```

Again, this does not account for configurability. How to do that?

```
$c = new Container();
$c->typicalCar = function ($c) {
    return new Car($c->regularEngine);
}
$c->regularEngine = function () {
    return new RegularEngine();
}
$c->vipCar = function ($c) {
    return new Car($c->advancedEngine);
}
$c->advancedEngine = function () {
    return new AdvancedEngine();
}
$carForTypicalCustomer = $c->regularCar;
$carForVipCustomer = $c->vipCar;
```

There we are: The building plans for the two types of cars are moved into closures that are doing the correct stuff, and you still have to decide if you want the one or the other type of car - there is no boolean parameter anymore, but I hope I gave you the impression that usually in applications you don't have such a parameter affecting the build process of objects at the composition root. Adding such a parameter there is a non-existing problem. But what if your really want it? Just imagine that the type of car comes from a configuration file or something:

```
$c = new Container();
$c->car = function ($c) {
    return new Car($c->engine);
}
$c->engine = function ($c) {
    return ($c->engineType) ? new AdvancedEngine : new RegularEngine;
}
$c->engineType = function () { 
    return true; 
}
$carForTypicalCustomer = $c->car
```

Instead of using a fixed `return true` for the engine type, you can add any code that reads configuration from somewhere.

Note that in this state of my example, this short DI container already comes to it's edge cases. It would be more convenient to assign the scalar values directly instead or having to encapsulate them in closures. More advanced DI containers have this feature - for example look at [Pimple](http://pimple-project.org/).

Even more advanced DI containers will look at the code of the class that is requested to be instantiated and try to figure out by themself (or with the help of code annotations), which other depended classes need to be instantiated.

For example, [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/) has a very nice autowiring feature that will simply try to call `new $typehint` if the typehint in the constructor points to a single class. In your case, the typehint points to an interface which cannot be instantiated, and you are required to tell PHP-DI which implementation you need. You have to select either the RegularEngine or the AdvancedEngine.

Note that the advanced DI containers will usually treat any created object to have singleton behavior, i.e. they will only create one instance when first asked for it, and on subsequent requests will return the SAME instance. So it makes no use to add configurability for the engine - as long as the Car object is used as a long-term object, this will be completely ok.

If however you need plenty of new instances, you *could* add a factory class into the DI container, and inject this factory where car instances are needed, and this factory might just provide one simple method with the boolean parameter and emit new car instances with different engines all day long. However, short-term objects don't belong into the composition root, and therefor are not in the scope of dependency injection (as the general concept) or DI containers - they belong to the application code, aka "business logic". And if the Car object and the Engines belong to the same domain, or are located in the same package, it is perfectly valid to just call `new Car(new RegularEngine)` if there is no need for ANY more customization. Most often you don't need perfect configurability for everything, you only need one specific job done. That's the time to only do THAT ONE job, and nothing in addition. [You ain't gonna need it! (YAGNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it)

Comment: First things first.

“How many cars does your application need, and when” I used the factory pattern because I need many these objects and all in runtime — the second option that you proposed.

Comment: “it is perfectly valid to just call new” — This means that every time I call CarFactory, I'll get the real car with real engine, no matter what arguments I pass to it! — This is the direct dependency hardcoding! Doesn't that completely break the DI principle? Or it's OK to break it in factories? I thought that it's allowed only in composition root, and it's forbidden in business logic or model classes, isn't it? And in this case, as you said, CarFactory doesn't belong to the composition root… So, why is it allowed to break the rules here? Is it a commonly used practice among the DI followers?

Comment: Tweetie&Pimple. I'd prefer to avoid using them, because they're simple Service locators, which is commonly known as an anti-pattern. I'd prefer using PHP-DI or Auryn instead — they allow real dependency injection and autowiring (you've mentioned the latter). But my question isn't about using a DIC — it's about the correct implementation of factory that has to create object with its dependencies in runtime an should follow the DI pattern at the same time. If I understand correctly, it has nothing to do with using a concrete DIC: whether you use any of them or not — the problem remains the same.

Comment: “DI containers will usually treat any created object to have singleton behavior.” Yes, usually, but this can be configured. For example, PHP-DI has the “scope” method which only purpose is to configure that behavior. Also, this behavior can be controlled in factories: one may inject container to his factory and call $container->make to create new instance, or call $container->get to fetch instance according to its “scope” policy.

Comment: “Using __invoke() makes code unclear” I use the PHP-DI DIC, therefore I called the method “__invoke”. Because of this, I don't have to specify which method should be invoked by injector. Otherwise, I would have to specify it in the container definitions array — the latter is possible too, but I prefer to avoid it.

Comment: “Boolean restricts the result of this factory” — there possibly could be much more parameters. This is just a very simple example of factory that contains business logic and creates objects with their dependencies at runtime.

Comment: “Your overwhelming amount of additional interfaces for your second car factory comes from the fact that you started to create a dependency injection framework” — not exactly. As I said, I already use PHP-DI. Its authors recommend to type-hint against interfaces, not implementations — to decrease the dependency. Also, in SOLID principle I stands for “interface segregation”, and how would one segregate something that doesn't exist :) Therefore, I use interfaces. Though, the use of them doesn't require using a DIC.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am tempted to write longer answers to almost all of your seven comments, but Stack Overflow simply isn't built to discuss matters in depth. Just as an example: Tweetie, Pimple, PHP-DI or Auryn are all both DI frameworks as well as service locators. Their role simply depends on where they are used. If they themselves get injected and used somewhere outside of the composition root, then they fulfill the service-locator-anti-pattern. Using them only at composition root makes all of them perfectly valid DI containers.

Comment: Maybe your question is too big and should be reduced to the very problem you are facing. I fear my answer is also too big. It seems like you have a concrete question about a situation where you are in need of something that dynamically allows creating plenty of objects, but linked to an application setup with DI. I think a question like "How would you ..." might lead to useful results if you also state what your perception of how DI should work (you are not new to DI anymore, you know a whole lot of things already).

Comment: Could you please provide an example (or link to it) of how Pimple can be used not as a service locator, but as a dependency inector, which injects the whole object tree — the dependencies of the composition root ojbect, and its dependencies, and their and so on — but so that all of this dependencies don't depend on the injector itself? Is it possible with Pimple or Tweetie? I didn't find such examples in web. Maybe, I searched poorly? The creators of Auryn and PHP-DI (if I'm not mistaken) say that this is the main difference between their DICs and those.

Comment: Pimple implements the `container-interop`-Interface just the way PHP-DI does. And I can inject both into the Slim 3 `App` object as the only constructor parameter. They only have to be configured right. Sure, PHP-DI does a lot of automagic, and spends lots of effort to reduce the necessary amount of manual configuration, and this is a good thing. Pimple on the other hand requires ANYTHING to be configured manually. However, this simple example shows that they are the same. You get the service-locator anti-pattern if your business code has a dependency on any container. Avoid it, and its fine.

Comment: When you inject the injector into your class and call injector's method “get” directly from your class (not from composition root) — this is the service locator pattern.

Sure, they all can be used as service locators. But Pimple cannot be used as an Injector, while PHP-DI and Auryn can — this is the main difference.

Comment: What do you do with PHP-DI that cannot be done with Pimple?

Comment: It is written in multiple places that Pimple isn't an injector, but only a service locator. And for me, it was not obvious how to use it as an injector. I've read the docs on official site, and concluded that there is no possibility to use it as an injector. But today, after your comments, I finally realized how exactly Pimple, as you've said (exactly the same as PHP-DI and Auryn) may be used both as an injector and as a service locator. The only difference between them is that Pimple doesn't support Interop\Container interface. So, thank you, Sven, without your help I would understand that.

Comment: And by writing that Pimple implements interop\container interface, did you mean the github package «moufmouf/pimple-interop», or does original Pimple support this?

Comment: If I stated somewhere that Pimple implements Container-Interop, i was wrong. There are additional packages that do this, like the one you mentioned, or xtreamwayz/pimple-container-interop for version 3. slim/slim 3.0 also extends Pimple and implements the interface in `Slim\Container`.

Comment: I mistyped, of course: I meant «So, thank you, @Sven, without your help I would *NOT* understand that»